# How to access work queue via code stage in Blue Prism?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

Is it possible to handle the work queue that drives a production server via CodeStage and input processes as arguments to the code stage?

**Update:** The current process uses a work queue to lock one robot at a time to work items. This queue is feeded from an excel table and requests that each production contains a "Work Queue Handler" as process. This "Work Queue Handler" is generic and largely copied from one project to another with minor changes (variables names ...). The specific process is in another process module and linked inside the "Work Queue Handler" queue.

I am wondering if it is possible to minimize the copiyng of the whole work queue logic into each new project and instead handle work assignement to robots inside a Code Stage.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case you're attempting to achieve? "Work queue that drives a production server" doesn't make much sense in a Blue Prism context.

Comment: @esqew: Updated. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: You might be able to leverage Work Queue tagging and Active Queue functionality to achieve what you're going for here. For instance, if a particular work item *must* be worked by a particular robot, tagging it with that instances' hostname and then using a tag filter on your Get Next Item stage within your process to only grab items for that particular Runtime Resource component. If the Work Item must be worked by a different Blue Prism Process entirely, you may consider utilizing a multi-queue strategy, or adding more tags to further differentiate each Work Item.